# Hide and Show Rows in Sheet2 depending on values on Sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with this issue for a week and haven't been able to make it right.

I have several cells in sheet1 in that when empty, the corresponding cell in sheet2 will be hidden, once the cell in sheet1 is NOT empty, the corresponding cell in sheet2 will be shown. For example:

*Sheet1:*

A1, A5, A10, A15 will be the cells that If blank, then:

- If A1 is blank, then sheet2 row 1 will be hidden, once it's not blank, the row will be shown.
- If A5 is blank, then sheet2 row 2 will be hidden, ....
- If A10 is blank, then sheet2 row 3 will be hidden, ... and so on

The objective is that if someone types their name on A1 (for example), the row in sheet 2 will be shown, and they will use the information of that row. If the person decided to write the name in A5, then the row 2 from sheet 2 will be shown, instead and so on...

Is there a way to use VBA code to do that automatically so that it is easy to use for other people?

Comment: WorksheetName.Rows(row#).Hidden = True or False, the trickier part for you will be the checking of the cells on the other sheet to see if they are blank or contain a string, selection change perhaps?  Do you have any code up and running?

Comment: I don't have any code. I already tried WorksheetName.Rows... but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: look into worksheet_change event and intersect